# NUMA node interleaving doesn't work for MariaDB

Tags: mariadb, numa

Please help activating NUMA node interleaving for MariaDB.

Using MariaDB 10.1.21 on CentOS Linux release 7.3.1611.

Per instructions on https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/systemd/ added /etc/systemd/system/mariadb.service.d/custom.conf:

```
[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/numactl --interleave=all /usr/sbin/mysqld $MYSQLD_OPTS $_WSREP_NEW_CLUSTER $_WSREP_START_POSITION
```

/var/log/messages shows that numactl is invoked:

```
Feb 23 10:40:46 host systemd: Starting MariaDB database server...
Feb 23 10:40:46 host numactl: 2017-02-23 10:40:46 140580844599552 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 10.1.21-MariaDB) starting as process 37349 ...
Feb 23 10:40:51 host systemd: Started MariaDB database server.
```

But numastat shows NUMA node interleaving doesn't work:

```
[root@host ~]# numastat -p $(pidof mysqld)

Per-node process memory usage (in MBs) for PID 37349 (mysqld)
                           Node 0          Node 1           Total
                  --------------- --------------- ---------------
Huge                         0.00            0.00            0.00
Heap                         0.00            0.00            0.00
Stack                     2711.53         1330.39         4041.92
Private                  23868.98         6126.55        29995.54
----------------  --------------- --------------- ---------------
Total                    26580.51         7456.95        34037.46
```

As you can see there is a huge imbalance between Node 0 and Node 1.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend starting first with checking if that policy had been applied for real. Check out if `/proc/…PID-of-interest…/numa_maps` has entries denoted as `interleave:`.

For e. g.:

```
7ffecdccd000 interleave:0-1 stack anon=8 dirty=8 active=1 N0=4 N1=4 kernelpagesize_kB=4
```

(I'd assume you won't find such.)

Second thing that I can think of is:

```
[mysqld]
…
innodb_numa_interleave = on
…
[mysqld_safe]
…
numa_interleave = on
…
```

— At least Percona's scripts are handling the former setting and it can be so that if you haven't explicitly specified them they would be set to default's.